How to solve this probability problem?
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{F}$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be two probabilities which are mutually absolutely continuous on $\mathcal{F}$. We denote by $X_0$ the Radon-Nikodym density of $Q$ with respect to $P$ on $\mathcal{F}$. Show that the following two properties are satisfied:
(a) $0 < \mathbb{E}_P[X_0 \mid \mathcal{G}] < \infty$, $P$-a.s.;
(b)For every $\mathcal{F}$-measurable non-negative random variable f,
$\mathbb{E}_P[f X_0 \mid \mathcal{G}] = \mathbb{E}_Q[f \mid \mathcal{G}] \mathbb{E}_P[X_0 \mid \mathcal{G}]$
My attempt:
(a)trivial,just verify the property of Radon-Nikodym theorem.
(b)To prove it,I should use two fact as follows:
(i) For a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and sub-$\sigma$-fields $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$, the following property holds for any integrable random variable $X$:$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{H}] \mid \mathcal{G}] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}].$
(ii)For non-negative $\mathcal{F}$-measurable function $\mathbb{g}$,we have $
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{g}X \mid \mathcal{F}] = \mathbb{gE}[X \mid \mathcal{F}].$
then I can solve it as follows:
$\mathbb{E}_Q[\mathbb{E}_p[fX_0 \mid \mathcal{G}] \mid \mathcal{F}] =\mathbb{E}_Q[\mathbb{E}_P[fX_0 \mid \mathcal{F}] \mid \mathcal{G}] =\mathbb{E}_Q[f\mathbb{E}_P[X_0 \mid \mathcal{F}] \mid \mathcal{G}]=\mathbb{E}_Q[f \mid \mathcal{G}] \mathbb{E}_P[X_0 \mid \mathcal{G}]$
The problem comes from S.-T. Yau College Student Mathematics Contests 2014
Probability and Statistics Problems Individual
Is my prove true? Any help is much appreciated.
